# create array of session object in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a class containing two list prop and i want those list element to be in Session. So i did tried the below code. but i didn't how to get the asked property and skipped property of each person object.

```
class Interrogation
{
    //list contains asked questions
    private List<int> _asked = new List<int>();
    public List<int> asked
    {
        get { return _asked; }
        set { _asked = value; }
    }

    //list contains skipped questions
    private List<int> _skipped = new List<int>();
    public List<int> skipped
    {
        get { return _skipped; }
        set { _skipped = value; }
    }
}
   protected void UploadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        testmulList();
        readSession();
   }
    protected void testmulList()
    {
        Interrogation person1 = new Interrogation();
        person1.asked.Add(8);
        person1.skipped.Add(7) = 67;
        Session["person1"] = person1;
    }
    protected void readSession()
    {
        var output = Session["person1"];
        Debug.WriteLine(output);
    }
```

When i tried **Debug.WriteLine(output)** i did not get any output.

Question:
1. How do i read the separate prop from the session object 
2. What if i create a object list and perform the same. again leads to question 1.

Comment: You sample makes no sense for ASP.Net app so far - please explain how your class invoked during page rendering.

Comment: yes i perform this during a button click and i also have a button handler wrapped around this

Comment: inorder to make the question look simple i cropped the portion of the code involved and displayed in question

Comment: Does your code even compile? How can you call methods from a class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is an inconsistency between your session keys

`Session["people1"];` vs `Session["person1"];`

They have to match. Use the same session key

To print you can do the following:

```
protected void readSession()
    {
        var output = (Interrogation)Session["people1"];

        foreach(var skipped in output.skipped)
        {
           Debug.WriteLine(skipped);
        }

        foreach(var asked in output.asked)
        {
           Debug.WriteLine(asked);
        }
    }
```

Comment: oops its just a typo, sorry.

Comment: I have added an example of how to print